# ANGULAR: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes

Tags: angular, routes

I'm having trouble with routing. I'm getting an error when I try to navigate to a component and I can't figure out what's the origin of the problem

Here is the function that I use for navigating. It's located in the edit-list component (represented by ' ' in the routing module).

```
displayComponent(displayMode:number, index:number){
      if(!this.emptyArray){
        this.router.navigate(['edit-list/edit', displayMode, index]);
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['edit-list/empty']);
      }  
    }
```

this the routing module for my lazy loaded component

```
const recipesRoutes:Routes = [
    {path:'',   component: EditCatsComponent, children: [
        {path: 'edit/:displayMode/:id/', component: CatEditComponent},
        {path: 'new', component: CatNewComponent},
        {path: 'empty', component: NoCatComponent}
        ], canActivate:[AuthGuard]}
    ];
```

And here is the error I'm getting:

```
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'edit-list/edit/1/0'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'edit-list/edit/1/0'
    at ApplyRedirects.webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.es5.js:1466)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.es5.js:1441)
    at CatchSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:105)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:130)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:104)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:130)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:104)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:130)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:104)
    at LastSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:130)
    at ApplyRedirects.webpackJsonp.../../../router/@angular/router.es5.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.es5.js:1466)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.es5.js:1441)
    at CatchSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:105)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:130)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:104)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:130)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:104)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:130)
    at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:104)
    at LastSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:130)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:824)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:795)
    at zone.js:873
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:192)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:602)
    at ZoneTask.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:503)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1540)
```

Comment: where is edit-list?

Comment: edit-list is the parent component. In the routing module it's represented by ' '

Comment: it should match the route

Comment: indeed but it doesn't work

Comment: found the solution: in routing module the path must be 'edit/:displayMode/:id' instead of 'edit/:displayMode/:id/'

Answer (score 0):

Try the absolute url:

```
 this.router.navigate(['/edit-list/edit', displayMode,index]);
```